# Deploying contract to rinkbey does nothing

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-deployment, rinkeby, truffle-migration

I have been trying to deploy my contract to Rinkbey, but nothing seems happening.

I have earlier deployed contracts locally to ganache RPC and used `truffle migrate`
it worked fine and I was able to call deployed contract's method without any problem.

After that, I added following lines into truffle.js

```
rinkeby: {
  host: "127.0.0.1", // Connect to geth on the specified
  port: 8545,
  from: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", // find it from geth console by typing `eth.accounts` use the first one
  network_id: 4,
  gas: 5000000 
}
```

so it became

```
module.exports = {
  // See <http://truffleframework.com/docs/advanced/configuration>
  // to customize your Truffle configuration!
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*"
    },
    rinkeby: {
      host: "127.0.0.1", // Connect to geth on the specified
      port: 8545,
      from: "xxxxxxxxxxxx", // find it from geth console by typing `eth.accounts` use the first one
      network_id: 4,
      gas: 5000000 // Gas limit
    }
  }
};
```

My `migrations/1_initial_migration.js` is as follows:

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

and  `contracts/Migrations.sol` is as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  function Migrations() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

  function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}
```

after that, I stopped local running `geth` and ran following command to unlock the account to get ready for deploying contract to rinkbey

`geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --unlock="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`

then ran following command in different terminal window

`truffle compile; truffle migrate --network rinkeby`

and got this output

```
Using network 'rinkeby'.

Network up to date.
```

While I was expecting it should have shown me completed migration to rinkbey and contract address, but it 
just keep saying `Network is up to date`. Even I edited my contract a bit thinking, that may fire new migration. But that did not help. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE: I read somewhere, I need to delete the `build` folder, so I did it. Then ran `truffle compile; truffle migrate --network rinkeby` and got followings this time:

```
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/addition.sol...
Writing artifacts to ./build/contracts

Using network 'rinkeby'.

Network up to date.
```

Still I don't see deployed contract address?

Comment: Do you have `deployer.deploy(addition)` in a migration anywhere? It looks like you only have the Migration contract listed. You should have another deploy file called 2_deploy.js (it can be called anything as long as it starts with 2_). The contents should be nearly the same as 1_initial_migration.js, but describes how to deploy your contract (constructor arguments, dependencies, etc).

Comment: @AdamKipnis I can see only one file under my `migrations` folder and that is 1_initial_migration.js and I have posted that file content above in my description. That is the ONLY file which has `deployer.deploy(addition)` My other contract name is `addition.sol` so I think you are saying I should also see `2_addition.js` file under `migrations` folder? but I don't see any such file there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a new file called 2_deploy_contracts.js which will be automatically called after initial migration

1_initial_migration.js will only update the already deployed migrations contract

```
var myContract = artifacts.require("MyContract");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(myContract);
};
```

Comment: Thank Nico. But can you educate me why should I create this second file. It should have auto generated by truflle when I run `truffle compile; truffle migrate --network rinkeby` ? isn't it? I think you have a typo ..first line of the migration `artifact path` should be `artifacts.require("./MyContract");`

Comment: Truffle will look in the contracts folder by default actually. This require statement is not to be confused with node's require statement. Maybe not such a clear naming convention on truffle's part. 

afaik this file is not auto-generated because this is where you would also specifiy constructor parameters and truffle can not auto-generate those. 

eg. `deployer.deploy(myContract, param1, param2, ... , options)`

Quote from the docs: "From here, you can create new migrations with increasing numbered prefixes to deploy other contracts and perform further deployment steps."

Comment: Got it.. thanks @nico. Accepting your answer. You should still correct the path `artifacts.require("MyContract");` to `artifacts.require("./MyContract");`